# Unable to use custom authentication backend in Django

Tags: django

I created a custom user model using AbstractBaseUser class. Code for the same is here.

```
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    user_type_choices = (
                            (constants.USER_TYPE_ADMIN, 'Admin'),
                            (constants.USER_TYPE_INSTITUTE, 'Institute'),
                            (constants.USER_TYPE_STUDENT, 'Student')
                        )
    sys_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, null=False, blank=False)    
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=127, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)  
    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=user_type_choices, null=False, blank=True, help_text="Admin(1)/Institute(2)/Student(3)")  
    access_valid_start = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    access_valid_end = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_when = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True )
    created_by = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated_when = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    last_updated_by = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=2048, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS must contain all required fields on your User model, 
    # but should not contain the USERNAME_FIELD or password as these fields will always be prompted for.
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'mobile', 'user_type']

    class Meta:
        app_label = "accounts"
        db_table = "users"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def is_access_valid(self):
        if self.access_valid_end > utility.now():
            return True
        else:
            return False


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        if not self.sys_id:
            self.created_when = utility.now()
        self.last_updated_when = utility.now()
        return super(UserModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Code for its manager is as below.

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True
    def create_user(self, email, name, mobile, user_type, password):      
        return create_superuser(self, email, name, mobile, user_type, password)

    # python manage.py createsuperuser
    def create_superuser(self, email, name, mobile, user_type, password):
        user = self.model(
                          email = email,
                          name = name,
                          mobile = mobile,
                          user_type = user_type,
                          access_valid_start = utility.now(),
                          access_valid_end = utility.get_access_end_date(),
                          created_when = utility.now(),
                          created_by = constants.COMMAND_LINE_USER_ID, 
                          last_updated_when = utility.now(),
                          last_updated_by = constants.COMMAND_LINE_USER_ID,
                          notes = 'This user is created from command line. createsuperuser utility.'
                          )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

I also created the Authentication Backend.

```
class MyAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, email, password):
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            else:
                return None
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("user with login %s does not exists " % login)
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("user with login %s does not exists " % login)
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        # user_id must be the primary key of table.
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(sys_id=user_id)
            if user.is_active:
                return user
            return None
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            logging.getLogger("error_logger").error("user with %(user_id)d not found")
            return None
```

I have included custom user model and backend, both in settings file.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserModel'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('accounts.backends.MyAuthBackend',)
```

I created a superuser from command line but when I tried to login from admin login url, following error was thrown.

```
Please enter the correct email and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.
```

As suggest in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18974592/2291289), I used fallback authentication backend and then it started throwing this error : `'UserModel' object has no attribute 'has_module_perms'`. Which means fallback backend worked here. But it required to add below functions in custom user model.

```
def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_superuser

    # this methods are require to login super user from admin panel
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser
```

and added is_superuser field as well. Now it is working fine.

So I have below questions :

1. Why I am not able to authenticate user using custom backend when trying to login from admin panel?
2. why function has_perm, `is_staff` and `is_superuser` fields are mandatory for login from admin panel?
3. Why has_perm function , is_staff and is_superuser fields are not required when logging in from my own login form?

Answer (score 0):

1. You did authenticate but you are not authorized. Django Admin is using [is_staff](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) flag to authorize you in as stated in documentation
2. They are part of Django simple permission system which is by default used by Django admin as stated in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization)
3. You are not using permissions system otherwise they would be required as they are part of permission system.