# Cannot log in to admin site with superuser account, which was created with console // Django

Tags: python, django

I have custom user model. After creating superuser in console I can't log in this account. Django says "Invalid username or password". But username and password are valid. I tried to fix this problem with next solution ([Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971928/cant-login-to-django-admin-after-creating-a-super-user-with-a-custom-user-model/18974592)), but it hadn't helped me.

My models.py:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Email required')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email, 
            username=username,
            is_active=True, 
            **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, username, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True')

        return self._create_user(email, username, password, **extra_fields)
```

My settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
)


AUTH_USER_MODEL = "backend.User"
```

Comment: When you say custom user model, what method have you used to customise it?

Comment: I created in model.py class User. Full models.py: [link](https://codeshare.io/5ZP8R7)

Comment: When creating the user, what parameter did it ask for? You might need the email instead of the username, or vice-versa

Comment: What do you see if  you do `dumpdata` on your users after you create the superuser?